# Description with Vbox Seems to Ignore Margins

Tags: margins, geometry, description

I have searched a few times, and have not found anything on here which fixes my issue. Essentially, I am using the geometry package with a margin of 0.75in; however, when I use the vbox with a description, the margins don't seem to be enforced at 0.75in anymore, and instead it goes (nearly) to the very left and right of the page.

In order to force the left side, I can use `\indent` but I'm not sure about how to fix the right side. I also don't think this is the best idea, since it is more of a cheat. Here is basically what I am doing:

```
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{description}
    \indent\vbox{
        \phantomsection
        \label{def:one}
        \item[One] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. In massa tempor nec feugiat. 
    }
    \indent\vbox{
        \phantomsection
        \label{def:two}
        \item[Two] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. In massa tempor nec feugiat. 
    }
    \indent\vbox{
        \phantomsection
        \label{def:three}
        \item[Three] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. In massa tempor nec feugiat. 
    }
\end{description}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

It would appear that this is caused by the vbox (when I remove it, both the right and left margin is respected); however I use the vbox to prevent the description from splitting at page boundaries; and also to use the phantom section and label, so removing it isn't a practical option for me.

Comment: `\vbox` is not a latex command and should never appear in a document, use `\parbox`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What is wrong with vbox? I've seen it used before (even on here) as a way to prevent the page breaks. Is it just deprecated in favour of parbox, or is there some other issues with it? Switching to parbox did fix the issue though.

Comment: In any case, the width of `\vbox` is `\hsize`.  You would need to add `\advance\hsize by -\parindent`.

Comment: latex defines  all its box commands to work in a consistent way, eg lists inside parbox (but not vbox) know their target width,  a parbox inside a center environment will be centred (vbox will not) etc... `\vbox` is a tex primitive which is unfortunately "visible" in latex due to the macro expansion nature of the latex implementation, but it is not a latex command and should not be used in documents. (You can use it to implement latex commands, if done with care)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That makes it much clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use thing like `\parbox` instead

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.75in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{description}
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \phantomsection
        \label{def:one}
        \item[One] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. In massa tempor nec feugiat. 
    }
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \phantomsection
        \label{def:two}
        \item[Two] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. In massa tempor nec feugiat. 
    }
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \phantomsection
        \label{def:three}
        \item[Three] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. In massa tempor nec feugiat. 
    }
\end{description}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)